# problems creating an executable file with .o files in different folders using g++

Tags: c++

I have two c++ files at different locations

1. hello.cc in /home/testing/src/impl/hello.cc
2. messages.cc in /home/testing/src/msg/messages.cc

in hello.cc we have an include for messages.h

so i was sucessfull to compile hello.cc using below command
g++ -c -I/home/testing/src/msg hello.cc (this generated an hello.o file in /home/testing/src/impl/)

now i compiled the messages.cc using command
g++ -c messages.cc (this generated an messages.o file in /home/testing/src/msg/)

**now what i want is to make and executable file using hello.o**

using below command

g++ -o hello hello.o

this is the error i am getting

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
message                             hello.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to hello
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

You need to load *all the object files*:

```
g++ -o hello hello.o path/to/messages.o
```

since the linker has no automatic way of knowing where to find the symbols.

Comment: say if i have so many objects at different different locations then how to solve that issue

Comment: @Tapsi Using a makefile, or by bundling multiple object files into static libraries, or both.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be,

```
g++ hello.o message.o -o hello  // give the proper paths
```

For making the main executable, you have include all the needed object files with their proper paths. Otherwise it will result in linker error